# PHP Laravel SQL Or Elequent Or Query builder

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel `5.4.` I am facing a big problem to make decision whether I should focus on mySQL or Elequent or query builder to make complex query.

For example: I need a electric bill report based on different charge range.

```
0-99=>$120
100-199=>$200
200-299=>$220
300-399=>$250
```

How can make a elequent query or query builder to make a report with other data such as Customer name, address, phone, sum of total, with details list of which range is being charged to him etc?

Should I use raw SQL query for this?

As I am using AngularJs, I have to return all this in a single query. If you want to help me using a controller, you can show me.

What can I do?

I used .Net where I can make this easily by LINQ query, but I am stuck here!

I think laravel query builder is not powerful like LINQ. Leave .Net if you are not familiar with it.

Anyways, I need help to get out of the problem. How can I write that complex query?

*Desired result*:

Suppose I have `Customers` table, `Billranges` table and `Bill` table

I need:

```
Customername-Address-Metter-Charge-Bill
John-Dhaka-250-$220 -55000(250x220)
```

Can I do this in Laravel 5.4 Query builder?

Comment: I think laravel provides this (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins)

Comment: It is only simple join example. How can i make logic within join to calculate?

Comment: laravel does provide this, you can even use the RAW command to use raw sql in laravel. If you setup your database tables properly and with correct relations then Eloquent can do this very easily and with minimal code.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: You don't have to stick with one way of doing queries. Use the best option that fits your query.

Comment: I suggest you use the best tool for the job, if the solution is simplest to do in sql, then do it in sql. I suggest you wrap your query in a method, for example in a repository class. For simpler queries I think eloquent is great!